# How to return only the documents that contain the specified field in the query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

For example, I have the query:

```
db.person.find({$and:[{name: "Jack"},{married: {$not: {$eq: "no"}}}]})
```

The result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2d199ddde29047871b5181"), "name" : "Jack", "age" : 20 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d38cdf960b4663b4581ed5d"), "name" : "Jack", "age" : 19 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d38ce1a60b4663b4581ed5e"), "name" : "Jack", "married" : "yes" }
```

How can I return only the line that have name and married like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d38ce1a60b4663b4581ed5e"), "name" : "Jack", "married" : "yes" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": "Jack",
  "married": { "$ne": "no", "$exists": true }
})
```

Actually You need to check for two condition for `married` field. One where it `$exists` and one where it is `$ne` to "no"